# Trigonometric Integral Estimate

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, integral-inequality

I want to make the following estimate:
$$\int_{-\pi} ^ {\pi} \left| \frac{\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) -\cos\left(\frac{(2N+1)x}{2}\right) }{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} \right| dx \le c \log (N) $$ 
The integrand is the absolute value of the so-called conjugate Dirichlet kernel defined by:
$$D_N (x) = \sum _{|n|<N} sign(x) e^{inx} $$

Any hints are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First observe that
$$\begin{aligned}|D_N(x)|&=\left|\sum_{n=1-N}^{N-1}e^{inx}\right|=\left|\frac{e^{i(1-N)x}(1-e^{i(2N-1)x})}{1-e^{ix}}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{e^{iNx}-e^{i(1-N)x}}{e^{ix}-1}\right|=\left|\frac{e^{i(N-\frac{1}{2})x}-e^{i(\frac{1}{2}-N)x}}{e^{\frac{1}{2}ix}-e^{-\frac{1}{2}ix}}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{\sin\left((N-\frac{1}{2})x\right)}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}\right|\leq\sum_{n=1-N}^{N-1}|e^{inx}|=2N-1
\end{aligned}$$
It follows that
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi|D_N(x)|dx&=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\left|\frac{\sin\left((N-\frac{1}{2})x\right)}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}\right|dx\\
&=2\int_{0}^\pi\left|\frac{\sin\left((N-\frac{1}{2})x\right)}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}\right|dx\\
&=4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left|\frac{\sin\left((2N-1)t\right)}{\sin t}\right|dt\\
\end{aligned}$$
Now recall that
$$|\sin t|\geq\frac{2t}{\pi},\quad\forall t\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}].$$
It follows that
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left|\frac{\sin\left((2N-1)t\right)}{\sin t}\right|dt&\leq \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4N-2}}\left|\frac{\sin\left((2N-1)t\right)}{\sin t}\right|dt+\int_{\frac{\pi}{4N-2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left|\frac{\pi\sin\left((2N-1)t\right)}{2t}\right|dt\\
&\leq \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4N-2}}(2N-1)dt+\int_{\frac{\pi}{4N-2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\pi}{2t}dt\\
&\leq C\log N
\end{aligned}$$
for appropriate choice of $C>0$.

Comment: You've approximated the wrong kernel but your procedure works for the other one, I used a similar method but the estimate |sin(t)|≥2tπ eluded me. Thanks for your help.